# How to override CSS using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an HTML page with three square images, every image is in a checkbox's label. I created a JavaScript function which checks how many checkboxes are checked.

On every input (which is a checkbox) I add an event listener, the goal of it is to limit The number of checked checkboxes to two. I used CSS so when an image is checked or hovered a red border appears.

My problem is that when I uncheck an image because my mouse is still on it I can't see that it was unchecked until my mouse isn't on the image.

So how can I override the CSS and hide or delete the border when an image is unchecked even if the mouse is still on it? I would like to use plain JavaScript for this.

```js
    function checkedtimes(checkboxes) {
        return checkboxes
        .map(checkbox => document.getElementById(checkbox).checked)
        .reduce((x, y) => x + y)
    }
    let logos = ["green","yellow","blue"]
    for (let logo of logos) {
        logo = document.getElementById(logo)
        logo.addEventListener('change', e=> {
            e.preventDefault()
            if (logo.checked) {
                if (checkedtimes(logos)>2) {
                    logo.checked = false
                }
            }
            else {
            
            }
        })
    }
```

```css
        
        #logos {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
       .logo {
            display: none;
        }
        .logo-label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .logo:checked + .logo-label>img, .logo:hover + .logo-label>img {
            border: solid 2px red;
        }
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">
        
        <div id="logos">
            <input type="checkbox" id="green" class="logo" />
            <label for="green" class="logo-label">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAS1BMVEUAgAAAewB9vX2MxIybzJsAeQCr1Ku42rgAdwC527mBv4HZ7NkAcwB0uXR4unj8/vzz9/Pk8OTP5s/I4siy17KRx5GgzqCOxY6ezZ4n9oUoAAABg0lEQVR4nO3dS24CQQwA0Z4/zQx/BnL/k2aQyCLZBCEhKHe9E7jkrSWn3f4wHk+nPORzv2jv5uaX+mnr5l9z+4BL/4ghD3+M6TytFt2P6mN1T5k2qe9SZFVdQOElfGFbvXuIl7KQz0I+C/ks5LOQr4jCOXxhYyGbhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIV0RhbSGbhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8hVRuA5fGP9iyEI4C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5Cui8Bq+MP6fGQvhLOSzkM9CPgv5LOSzkM9CPgv5LOSzkM9CPgv5LOSzkM9CPgv5iij8Cl/Yd+8e4qUs5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQbykcwhfm8IXxd2ghnIV8FvJZyGchn4V8FvLdCqcqstU2jZs6sm3+Bjn6EUWa4rsaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
            <br>
            green
        </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="yellow" class="logo"/>
            <label for="yellow" class="logo-label">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
            <br>
            yellow
        </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="blue" class="logo"/>
            <label for="blue" class="logo-label">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
            <br>
            blue
        </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: If you want border on hover and on check then you need to toggle any different class on logo input  like active and give border css on active class.

this will separate both css on hover and on checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more js oriented solution but I guess can work for you.

I am using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on `img` to simulate **hover**.

An additional `click` event on the `img` such that if the `logo` was checked and you clicked on the `img`, the `border` will be set to `none` else `border` will be set to `solid 2px red`.

```js
function checkedtimes(checkboxes) {
        return checkboxes
        .map(checkbox => document.getElementById(checkbox).checked)
        .reduce((x, y) => x + y)
    }
    let logos = ["green","yellow","blue"]
    for (let logo of logos) {
        logo = document.getElementById(logo)
        logo.addEventListener('change', e=> {
            e.preventDefault()
            if (logo.checked) {
                if (checkedtimes(logos)>2) {
                    logo.checked = false
                }
            }
            else {
            
            }
        })
        const image = logo.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;
       image.addEventListener('mouseenter',e=>{
         if(!logo.checked){
           image.style.border = 'solid 2px red';
         }
        })
        image.addEventListener('mouseleave',e=>{
        if(!logo.checked){
           image.style.border = 'none';
         }
        })
         image.addEventListener('click',e=>{
          if(logo.checked){
          image.style.border = 'none';
          }
          else {
          image.style.border = 'solid 2px red';
          }
         })
    }
```

```css
#logos {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
       .logo {
            display: none;
        }
        .logo-label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .logo:checked + .logo-label>img {
            border: solid 2px red;
        }
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">
        
        <div id="logos">
            <input type="checkbox" id="green" class="logo" />
            <label for="green" class="logo-label">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAS1BMVEUAgAAAewB9vX2MxIybzJsAeQCr1Ku42rgAdwC527mBv4HZ7NkAcwB0uXR4unj8/vzz9/Pk8OTP5s/I4siy17KRx5GgzqCOxY6ezZ4n9oUoAAABg0lEQVR4nO3dS24CQQwA0Z4/zQx/BnL/k2aQyCLZBCEhKHe9E7jkrSWn3f4wHk+nPORzv2jv5uaX+mnr5l9z+4BL/4ghD3+M6TytFt2P6mN1T5k2qe9SZFVdQOElfGFbvXuIl7KQz0I+C/ks5LOQr4jCOXxhYyGbhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIV0RhbSGbhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8lnIZyGfhXwW8hVRuA5fGP9iyEI4C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5Cui8Bq+MP6fGQvhLOSzkM9CPgv5LOSzkM9CPgv5LOSzkM9CPgv5LOSzkM9CPgv5iij8Cl/Yd+8e4qUs5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQz0I+C/ks5LOQbykcwhfm8IXxd2ghnIV8FvJZyGchn4V8FvLdCqcqstU2jZs6sm3+Bjn6EUWa4rsaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
            <br>
            green
        </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="yellow" class="logo"/>
            <label for="yellow" class="logo-label">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
            <br>
            yellow
        </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="blue" class="logo"/>
            <label for="blue" class="logo-label">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
            <br>
            blue
        </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's perfect for me! Just a question will it work if I put the 2 first event listener from the image on the logo?

Comment: logo has `display:none` so it won't work. That's why I chose your `img` element.

Comment: @SH The `else` bit for `click` event was missing so added that too.

Comment: Perfect ! I'll add it

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `style.setProperty(string, string)`. The first parameter is the **CSS atttribute** and the second parameter is the **CSS value**. Both of them need to be `strings` in order to work.

```
let element = document.getElementById("element-id")

element.style.setProperty('color', '#ffffff');
```

To know if the mouse is still hover the element you can create an event listener on the element.

```
element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    element.style.setProperty('color', '#ffffff');
});

element.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    element.style.setProperty('color', '#000000');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but here how can I know with javascript if the mouse is still on the image?

Comment: @SH I have updated the answer to your needs

Comment: Thank you very much! that will help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to your css styling, as you are displaying a border around the picture when the mouse hovers over it.
Please change your css by removing :hover

```
.logo:checked + .logo-label>img{
   border: solid 2px red;
}
```

Modified code snippet is below

```js
function checkedtimes(checkboxes) {
        return checkboxes
        .map(checkbox => document.getElementById(checkbox).checked)
        .reduce((x, y) => x + y)
    }
    let logos = ["green","yellow","blue"]
    for (let logo of logos) {
        logo = document.getElementById(logo)
        logo.addEventListener('change', e=> {
            e.preventDefault()
            if (logo.checked) {
                if (checkedtimes(logos)>2) {
                    logo.checked = false
                }
            }
            else {
            
            }
        })
    }
```

```css
        #logos {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
       .logo {
            display: none;
        }
        .logo-label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            
        }
       .logo:checked + .logo-label>img{
            border: solid 2px red;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form">
        
        <div id="logos">
            <input type="checkbox" id="green" class="logo" />
            <label for="green" class="logo-label">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
            <br>
            green
        </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="yellow" class="logo"/>
            <label for="yellow" class="logo-label">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
            <br>
            yellow
        </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="blue" class="logo"/>
            <label for="blue" class="logo-label">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
            <br>
            blue
        </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Just run code and check does it fit to you